# How much research are we expecting questioners to do?

Tags: discussion

I'm still working through the meta etc, having come over from Bio.SE.  There seems to be a whole slew of what I would consider "low quality" questions, where it seems minimal effort was put into both asking the question and thinking on the topic.

For example, in Bio I would begin to think of answering [this question](https://health.stackexchange.com/questions/1059/would-it-be-better-to-have-fruits-on-an-empty-stomach-rather-after-a-full-meal) if the poster didn't include what article they were reading, and would prefer if they took a stab as to why they thought the supposition was true.

The format of these question seems to be:

1. Personal/unnamed source of inspiration ("my teacher said," "I read," "a wombat told me," etc.)
2. An unusual supposition (true, untrue, or not really testable/valid)
3. A request for support of the supposition

Am I way off base here?  I really don't mean to be critical and I'm quite interested to see the future of the site.  I chose the question above because it happens to even have a [Snopes article](http://www.snopes.com/food/warnings/fruit.asp).

Comment: While I share your desire for better quality questions, you came to Bio approx 1.5 years after the private beta and public launch. I would hazard a guess that the early bio questions showed much the same level as some of ours do now.

Comment: @JohnP I'm not entirely sure that's relevant to the issue though (but I agree it's likely true).  I would want to ask the OP for a reference to the article in question at the least, and probe for more logic at the best.  I took a more serious swing at answering the question anyway (working in Peds I stay up on nutrition but it's never been my focus).  I still think the question should have edit requests, but I want to know if that's the general opinion on the site or not.

Comment: I'm closing this as a duplicate of the newer question because that one is more relevant than this. I just don't want anyone to click here expecting an answer and never get one.

Comment: @michaelpri I have no problem with this. It is kind of funny to be closing the older post for duplicate, but I understand. Looking at the answers on the other question, I'm still not exactly sure on a good line.